# Populate all records from database with id also the values in select list

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm having a problem where I need to populate all the values from database in my select list for the second time. I have two select list the one is multiple list of the `users`. Second for the `categories` which I still don't have an idea.

Select list multiple

```
<div class = "form-group">
    <label for = "to" class = "control-label">To:</label>
    <select class = "form-control" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">

            @foreach ($result as $list)
                <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
            @endforeach

    </select>
</div>
```

Select list one

```
<div class = "form-group">

        <label for = "category" class = "control-label">Category:</label>
            <select class = "form-control">

                @foreach ($resultCategory as $categoryList)
                <option value = "{{ $categoryList->id }}">{{ $categoryList->category_type }}</option>
                @endforeach

            </select>

</div>
```

Controller: as you can see here I passed the `$result` for the records of all user's in my `return view ('document.create')`

```
public function getDocuments()
{  
    $result = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();

    $resultCategory = DB::table('categories')->get();

    return view ('document.create')->with('result', $result);
```

}

I'm thinking how can I passed the `$resultCategory` in my `return view` for able to populate my records from my second select list. Because I already passed the value which is `$result`

Comment: return view ('document.create')->with('result', $result)->with('resultCategory', $resultCategory);

Answer (score 0):

I already find a solution. I just add with`('resultCategory', '$resultCategory')` for the second time.

```
$result = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();

$resultCategory = DB::table('categories')->get();

return view ('document.create')->with('result', $result)->with('resultCategory', $resultCategory);
```